# Nullpointer exception while creating table using CQL3?

Tags: cassandra, cql, astyanax, cql3

I am trying to create a table in cassandra DB using cql3 and it throws this error on cassadra server and the table is not created, can anyone tell, what is the reason behind it?

Script -->

```
use demodb1;

CREATE TABLE fishblogscolumnfamily (
    userid varchar,
    when timestamp,
    fishtype varchar,
    blog varchar,
    image blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, when, fishtype)
);
```

Error:

```
INFO 14:28:27,057 Create new ColumnFamily: 
org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@70177017[cfId=1024,ksName=demodb1,cfName=fishblogscolumnfamily,cfType=Standa,comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),subcolumncomparator=<null>,comment=,readRepairChance=0.1,dclocalReadRepairChance=0.0,replicateOnWrite=true,gcGraceSeconds=864000,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxCompactionThreshold=32,keyAlia
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6],columnAliases=[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4], java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8]],valueAlias=<n
l>,column_metadata={java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=5 cap=5]=ColumnDefinition{name=696d616765, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType, index_typ
null, index_name='null', component_index=2}, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]=ColumnDefinition{name=626c6f67, validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marsh
.UTF8Type, index_type=null, index_name='null', component_index=2}},compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrateg
compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionOptions={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor},bloomFilterFpChance=<null>,caching=KEYS
NLY]
ERROR 14:28:27,071 Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FastByteComparisons$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo(FastByteComparisons.java:223)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FastByteComparisons$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo(FastByteComparisons.java:110)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FastByteComparisons.compareTo(FastByteComparisons.java:41)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.compareUnsigned(FBUtilities.java:184)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned(ByteBufferUtil.java:89)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType.bytesCompare(BytesType.java:58)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType.compare(AsciiType.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType.compare(AsciiType.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:32)
        at java.util.TreeMap.rbInsert(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.TreeMapBackedSortedColumns.addColumn(TreeMapBackedSortedColumns.java:95)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractColumnContainer.addColumn(AbstractColumnContainer.java:109)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractColumnContainer.addColumn(AbstractColumnContainer.java:104)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.ColumnDefinition.toSchema(ColumnDefinition.java:195)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.toSchema(CFMetaData.java:1159)
```

Comment: please provide your Cassandra version

Comment: it's ok for me on 1.2; you may want to ask this question on user-list so that you could get help much faster. BTW, have you tried any other examples? Have they all failed with the same error?